# Understanding Memory Models

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, memory-model

I've been reading up on memory models recently and I was sort of confused on how this worked.

To quote http://cis.poly.edu/muller/CS623/weakmemory.htm

> if processor writes a new X then writes a new Y, all other processors that subsequently 
>   execute a read Y then a read X, will
>   access either the new Y and new X, the
>   old Y and the new X, or old X and the
>   old Y: but no processor will access
>   the new Y and the old X. This
>   assumption of strong ordering was, at
>   one time, reasonable. Current computer
>   manufactures, however, recommend that
>   programmers not rely on memory
>   ordering. This is because newer memory
>   management systems attempt to reorder
>   memory access for optimization
>   purposes. Systems that are allowed to
>   reorder memory request are called
>   weakly-ordered memory systems
>   (models). To examine how a reordering
>   might be used to improve performance,
>   consider the following assembler code
>   [2].

```
Load reg1, A                 // register1 = contents of memory A
Load reg2, B                 // register2 = contents of memory B
ADD reg3, reg1, reg2     // register3 = register1 + register2
Store reg3, C                 // contents of memory C = contents of register3
```

> If we assume that location B is
>   currently in cache and location A is
>   not cached, then loading A will take
>   longer than B. Instead of waiting for
>   A, the CPU can fetch B from its cache,
>   hiding B’s latency: thus the CPU can
>   perform the addition as soon as A is
>   available. By relaxing the strong
>   (sequential) memory model of execution
>   (i.e., A must load first, followed by
>   B), greater performance is
>   possible----but reordering may not be
>   transparent to software. Consider the
>   code fragment below, it is part of the
>   code that can be used to implements a
>   spinlock semaphore [2].

My question is, how is it possible that with a weaker memory model could lead to the case that a processor could access the new Y and old X. Isn't it written to the same memory (ram) or does it work differently? I assume if one process modifies a variable and another reads it after that, it reads the latest value.

Another thing I'm not sure about is which component allows memory access reordering, my assumption now is that a compiler is allowed to reorder instructions. But could a CPU also reorder them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must remember that cache sits between the CPU and memory. When to software writes a value it certainly lands in the cache, but it may never go to main memory at all if the value is written again before the cache copies it to RAM (think loop variables and locals). This whole discussion revolves around the different models for when data is actually placed in RAM or read from RAM. Within a core it doesn't really matter, as they will use that last value written weather it comes from cache or RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Both the compiler and the CPU can reorder instructions. See [Memory ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering)